# Split object periodically

Tags: modeling

I want to split an stl file into (say) 1mm segments in the x direction and apply convex hull to each individually.Any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Just about any question about if Blender can do something automatically is YES. How complex it is to actually get it to do the automation is another thing entirely. Open the Info window and watch the Python commands generated as you manually perform the tasks of a single step of the automation and then take that make it into a script. Will not be quite that easy but should give you enough information to Google the missing bits. Good luck and post the script as the answer here when done.